# Set a range to uppercase in sheets APP SCRIPT

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script that I will have in a menu that gets the range "A1:C" and uppercases it. The problem is that throws an error **"TypeError: values.toUpperCase is not a function"** trying to use `toUpperCase()`.

Got the following code:

```
function allUpper() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:C").getValues();
  var valuesUpper = values.toUpperCase();
  ss.getRange("A1:C").setValue(valuesUpper);
}
```

Im pretty new to JS and sheets api. I feel dumb because it looks like something simple.

**EDIT 1:** Now I know that .toUpperCase() doesnt work on arrays. But the proposed solutions of mapping the array and looping through the elements inside is still throwing the same error with `toUpperCase();`

**EDIT 2:** I upload a sample of my data requested by @NEWAZA
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi6iD.png)

Comment: try doing console.log(valuesUpper) ... I bet getValues returns an array and not just a string and hence your error since array object does not have a function called toUpperCase. You will have to iterate or map the array to uppercase each value.

Comment: Yes, it is an array, I didnt knew you couldn't use it on arrays. Anyways I tried to map the array and use toUpperCase() on every element but stills throws the same error.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your sheet data, please

Comment: @NEWAZA Added, the content extends to row 3000 but its just a test sheet

Comment: Updated my answer, blank cells are addressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function allUpper() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
                              .getRange("A1:C")

  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
                      .map(row => row.map(col => (col) ? col.toUpperCase() : col))

  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Once we get our values in `values`, we use `.map()` to loop over each row, and within each row, we loop over each cell/column and set to uppercase.

Another common way to do this is to use `for` loops and nest one inside of another.

Read More:

- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

An important thing to note when modifying a range of values is that you will need to make sure the range you are setting is the same 'size' as these values.

Originally you were getting values from `A1:C` and trying to set them into `A1`, which would not work due to difference in 'size'.

**Edit:**
Addressed blank cells in column/cell mapping.

```
(col) ? col.toUpperCase() : col
```

If item has value, modify it to `.toUpperCase()`, or leave be.

Answer (score 0):

[`Range.getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns 2 dimensional array. You will have to do `toUpperCase()` for each row and column

```
function allUpper() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange( "A1:C" ).getValues();

  for ( var row = 0; row < values.length; row++ ) {
      for ( var col = 0; col < values[ row ].length; col++ ) {
          values[ row ][ col ] = values[ row ][ col ].toUpperCase();
      }
  }

  ss.getRange( "A1:C" ).setValues( values );
}
```

Comment: This should works, but stills thows same error when using toUpperCase(); 

Even thought, I wanted to avoid using for loops like this because this function is goin to modify a large sheet, and I thing it would be slow. The "map" method seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an inefficient nested for loop when you can do the following:

```
values.map( function( row ) {
    return row.map( function( cell ) { 
        cell = cell.toUpperCase(); 
    } );
}
```

Comment: Now I understand how map works.
I think you missed a ")". Anyways stills throws "cell.toUpperCase() is not a function"
Maybe the problem is how i get the values?